# A515F Global version in Bootloop

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, boot-loop, unbricking, safe-mode

Anyone, please help, I charge the phone overnight at normal, wake up in the morning the phone is in bootloop Forever! (It's Samsung A51 Global version, A515F with the 5/18 firmware stock ROM, NO rooting, No custom ROM)
I even try Reiboot's repair function multiple times and it didn't work.
It did re-apply the latest Firmware to the phone for me but still cannot boot to android.

The phone is able to boot to recovery mode only, I cleaned up the dust of the internal also as it has no warranty at all. I am not attempting to fix the phone, I just wanna pull all the files of the internal memory back before I can factory reset it in Recovery mode.

I have the USB debugging activated. Any questions or details please ask, I can replace it with a new phone, but at least I can pull the data out, or better yet, able to boot it to the android system, I tried the safe mode method NOT working.

Comment: try to capture [logcat](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logcat/info) (and share via pastebin.com if you are not concerned about privacy)